# Using certain data points twice in the same analysis?

Tags: time-series, repeated-measures

I've conducted an experiment where my experimental group was subject to a manipulation (M) with four levels (1, 2, 3, 4).

Before this manipulation, the participant had to decide on a value within a certain range (V1). After this decision, he was shown the manipulation (either level 1, 2, 3, 4), also within a certain range. After the manipulation was presented, he received feedback information (FI) regarding his primary decision.

A hypothetical example:

[image]

This is usually considered to be one trial (so similar to tasks in social decision making (e.g. ultimatum game), where you have player 1 (V1) who decides on what amount to share and he receives a response from player 2 whether he accepts it or not (FI).

However, I would like to test, whether the difference between V1 from one trial and the V1 (I named it "V2" in the sheet) from the **next** **trial** is statistically significant when the manipulation was level 3 and FI was of a certain value (just an example).

So this basically means that every **V2** from **trial n** is at the same time **V1** of the **trial n + 1**.

I'm not entirely sure how to proceed with the analysis of such data, considering I would be using the same data points as two different variables in the same analysis. Is this even allowed? Are there any statistical tools with which I can remedy this issue, or is this not an issue at all and I'm overthinking this?

Answer (score 0):

This sort of thing is actually common. You basically need to model a dataset produced by the self-join of your datatable. The main difficulty with this is sometimes the joined dataset is n^2 big or similar, but if your number of trials per person is much smaller than the number of people, you shouldn't have much of an issue.

There is a symmetry that results in the input dataset but it is natural because you are modeling a continuous domain (i.e. time). These convolutional analysis topics are common in time series and image processing.

Comment: Thank's a lot for your answer. I don't have any experience in analyzing time series (and image processing) data yet so I was a bit confused by this, as it seemed to be somewhat strange.